# Sorting information in a column with script in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to sort data in column A (High, Med, Low) based on level of priority and do so automatically anytime a new entry is made in a new row. So regardless of what order I enter my information, it will ensure that all the High Priority are together, all medium are together etc....

I should also make it clear that I am new to the script world so I apologize in advance!

I should note that I have multiple sheets within the spreadsheet and only want this applied to my first sheet.  I tried using the script below and I receive the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')
onEdit  @ onEdit.gs:2

````
    function onEdit(event){
          var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
          var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    
          var columnToSortBy = 1;
          var tableRange = "A:L";
    
          if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
            var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
            range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy } );
          }
        }
    ```

I do have another onEdit function.  Could this be the issue?

    function onEdit(event){
      var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
      var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    
      var columnToSortBy = 1;
      var tableRange = "A:L";
    
      if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
        var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
        range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy } );
      }
    }
````

Answer (score 1):

From your showing script, if you are using 2 `onEdit` functions in the same Google Apps Script project, please remove one of them. Please use only one function of `onEdit`. Please be careful about this.

And, if you want to use your showing script to the 1st tab of the Spreadsheet, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit(event) {
  var { range, source } = event;
  var sheet = source.getActiveSheet();
  var columnToSortBy = 1;
  if (range.columnStart == columnToSortBy && source.getSheets()[0].getSheetName() == sheet.getSheetName()) {
    var tableRange = "A:L";
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort({ column: columnToSortBy });
  }
}
```

- In this modified script, when column "A" of the 1st tab is edited, the script in the if statement is run.
- As additional information, when you want to use only the specific sheets, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      if (range.columnStart == columnToSortBy && source.getSheets()[0].getSheetName() == sheet.getSheetName()) {
    ```
  - To

    ```
      if (range.columnStart == columnToSortBy && ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", , ,].includes(sheet.getSheetName())) {
    ```
  - In this case, please set the sheet names you want to use to `["Sheet1", "Sheet2", , ,]`.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your showing script works fine when the script is run to the 1st tab. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)